# Handling a JSON API with Django and putting the data in a model

Tags: json, django, api, django-models

I have a basic JSON API with some data, I need to dynamically get this data in python and put it in a model, more basically, Let's say the API is for cars, each car has a name and model, how to get the data from the JSON API for cars and put in a model called "Car" in models.py?

I searched but I couldn't find a way to do that.